# ORA-65096: nombre de usuario o rol común no válido

Tags: oracle, oracle-21c

estoy tratando de crear un usuario llamado PASARELA en el que pueda asignarle un tablespace con el objetivo de usarlo como gestor de este mismo, pero me tira el siguiente error:

```
CREATE USER PASARELA IDENTIFIED BY "Paradise30"  
DEFAULT TABLESPACE "RUNWAY"
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
ENABLE EDITIONS ;
```

> Informe de error -
> ORA-65096: nombre de usuario o rol común no válido
> 65096. 00000 -  "invalid common user or role name"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name
> that was not valid for common users or roles. In addition to the
> usual rules for user and role names, common user and role names
> must consist only of ASCII characters, and must contain the prefix
> specified in common_user_prefix parameter.
> *Action:   Specify a valid common user or role name.

estoy usando la version 21c express edition de oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error indica que la conexión que usas, está apuntando a la CDB y no a una PDB. ¿Te es familiar el cambio que hicieron en 12c donde imtrodujeron el concepto de PDB (pluggable databases)?

Pues bien, significa que tus esquemas y datos "de programa" deben vivir en una PDB que es más fácil de mantener y blabla, mientras que la configuración de la BD y la metadata de jobs y todo lo que hace oracle en segundo plano, vive en la CDB (container database). Una CDB puede estar asociada a cero o más PDB.

Esto también implica que las restricciones a los esquemas y demás datos en la CDB son mayores. Como en el nombre de usuario que intentas crear, que es muy largo (sí, así de estricto es el mundo de la CDB).

Entonces, debes conectarte a la instancia PDB que se crea por defecto en la instalación (según recuerdo, es `XEPDB1` en express edition).

Comment: como podría conectarme a la estancia y poder crear un tablespace con ese tipo de dato?

Comment: Un tablespace no tiene un tipo de dato. Como te dije en la respuesta, revisa los parámetros de conexión, no te conectes a orcl